# Copy dateTime text from one element into another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I would like to copy the dateTime text that is inside of the **eventDate** div into the **dateNumber** span element. With my current code, it will copy the first date it finds inside of **eventDate** and post it inside of every **dateNumber** span element, thus each date is repeated and not unique. I would like the unique content from each **eventDate** div to be reflected in the **dateNumber** span element.

I am using the formatted date time text both for sorting the parent divs and also for displaying the date in this format: "Aug 7th".

html:

```
 <div data-event-date="1407128400000" class="panel callout radius columns small-12 medium-6 large-4 August">
    <span class="dateNumber"></span>
    <span><a href="/community-calendar/city-council-meeting-august-2014">City Council Meeting</a></span>
    <div data-bc-date="format: MMM Do" class="hidden-for-small-up eventDate">Aug 7th</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(".eventDate").parent().appendTo($(".dateNumber"));
```

Comment: Your wording for the question is confusing. Can you please post and example of the expected HTML **after** the correct javascript would run?

Comment: @AdamMerrifield I can't as a lot of the data is pulled from the back end of the site. I will try to update my question to make it more clear and simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to set the **.eventDate** div value to the corresponding  **.dateNumber** corresponding div,you can do like this:

```
$(".eventDate").each(function(){

$(this).parent().find(".dateNumber").text($(this).text());

});
```

Comment: I figured an each function was what I needed, I just wasn't sure how to implement it correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to target the ancestor.

For a single panel:

```
$(".eventDate").closest(".panel").find("span.dateNumber") // added span for more accuracy
                        .text($(".eventDate").html‌​());
```

For multiple panel:

```
$(".eventDate").each(function(){
    $(this).closest(".panel").find("span.dateNumber").text($(this).html()); //added span for more accuracy
});
```